# terrraform get yaml values

Tags: yaml, terraform

I need to get the values from the yaml snippet into 1. the Route53 Zones where I need the apex_nme to be the zone names and 2. the records to be added as Route53 records into the specific zones. I have no clue how to do this. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for apex in var.source_domains : apex =>  {

      name = apex.name
      }
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  for_each = {
  for records in var.source_domains : records =>  {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.this[each.key].zone_id
    name    = subdomains.records
    type    = "A"
    records = ["192.168.0.1"]
  }
  }
}
```

```
source_domains:
  - apax_name: elastic2ls.com
    records:
      - elastic2ls.com
      - www.elastic2ls.com
  - apax_name: elastic2ls.ch
    records:
    - elastic2ls.ch
    - www.elastic2ls.ch
    - image.elastic2ls.ch
    - m.elastic2ls.ch
    - static.elastic2ls.ch
```

Comment: If your passing the contents of that yaml file in as `var.source_domains`, you just need to use `yamldecode()` to convert it into terraform data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is presented as if it's about YAML parsing, but I suspect you're really asking about how to write the `for_each` expression for `aws_route53_record.this` to create all of the records across all of the domains.

For completeness, I'll note that you could get `var.source_domains` to be populated from that YAML by making the calling module define that variable with an expression like this:

```
module "example" {
  source = "../modules/example"

  source_domains = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/example.yaml")).source_domains
  # ...
}
```

Inside the module itself then, I'd first declare that module with a suitable type constraint to make it clear what data structure we're expecting, like this:

```
variable "source_domains" {
  type = set(object({
    apax_name = string
    records   = set(string)
  }))
}
```

Here I defined both the top-level structure and the nested record as *set* types, because the way we're going to use them means that the ordering isn't important and we're expecting them all to be unique.

With all of that in place we can start to write out the resource definitions. Let's start with the zones, which are the simpler case because `var.source_domains` already meets the main requirement of having one element per resource instance we want to declare:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for d in var.source_domains : d.apax_name => d
  }

  name = each.value.apax_name
}
```

With the example YAML input you shared, this block will declare two instances of this resource:

- `aws_route53_zone.example["elastic2ls.com"]`
- `aws_route53_zone.example["elastic2ls.ch"]`

The `aws_route53_record` declaration is a little trickier because we need to project the input data structure into a new structure where there's one element per record we want to declare, rather than one element per *zone*. [Flattening nested data structures for `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each) is a common use for [the `flatten` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html), and we can adapt the networks and subnets example from the documentation to work with zones and records instead:

```
locals {
  zone_records = flatten([
    for d in var.source_domains : [
      for r in d.records : {
        zone_name = d.apax_name
        zone_id   = aws_route53_zone.example[d.apax_name].id
        record    = r
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

This [local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html) is constructing a list of objects where each object represents one valid pairing of zone and record. That means that the number of elements matches the number of `aws_route53_record` instances we need to declare, and so we can use this data structure in `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "example" {
  for_each = {
    for zr in local.zone_records : zr.record => zr
  }

  zone_id = each.value.zone_id
  name    = each.value.record
  # ...
}
```

This example diverges a little from the typical `flatten`/`for_each` pattern because all of your record names already have the zone name embedded in them anyway, and so we don't need the usual expression to generate a compound unique key with multiple parts, like `"${subnet.network_key}.${subnet.subnet_key}"` in the documentation's example. The record name alone is sufficient for a unique key across all pairs in this case.

This then, again based on your example YAML, will declare the following instances:

- `aws_route53_record.example["elastic2ls.com"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["www.elastic2ls.com"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["elastic2ls.ch"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["www.elastic2ls.ch"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["image.elastic2ls.ch"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["m.elastic2ls.ch"]`
- `aws_route53_record.example["static.elastic2ls.ch"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin Atkins. This works perfect.

Comment: Hi, I need to create certification validations based on this as well. I need ot set the zone id's of the apax domains for all corresponding subdomains.

Comment: It sounds like you now have a different problem (even if it is related to this first one) and so I'd suggest starting a new question for it, so you can re-share your latest configuration and what new configuration you've tried to add.